# iOS: How can I make this game reset button work properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a game where a fireball UIImage falls from the screen, and the user moves the player object with the touch screen to avoid them.  After 8 points, the playAgainButton pops up.  However, this playAgainButton button isn't working.  It doesn't execute any of the code in the ResetGame method, and it actually resets the position of my character object "Dustin", which I don't want to happen.  I have a referencing outlet attached to the button.  How can I get the code in ResetGame to work?  My ViewController code is below.

```
 int theScore;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self initializeTimer];
}

- (IBAction)ResetGame:(id)sender {  //only thing that actually happens right now is that Dustin resets for some reason.
    theScore = 0;

    [self updateScore];

    _Fireball.center = CGPointMake(64, 64);
    _endLabel.hidden = true;
    _playAgainButton.hidden = true;

    [self gameLogic:theTimer];
}

- (void)updateScore {
    _score.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",theScore];
}

- (void) initializeTimer {
    if(theTimer == nil)
    {
        theTimer = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(gameLogic:)];
    }

    theTimer.frameInterval = 1;
    [theTimer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void) gameLogic:(CADisplayLink *) theTimer {
    if((!CGRectIntersectsRect(_Fireball.frame, _Dustin.frame)) && (theScore < 8)){
        if(_Fireball.center.y >600){
            int num = arc4random() % 3;
            if(num == 0){
                _Fireball.center = CGPointMake(64, 64);
            }
            else if(num == 1){
                _Fireball.center = CGPointMake(192, 64);
            }
            else if(num == 2){
                _Fireball.center = CGPointMake(320, 64);
            }

            theScore = theScore + 1;
            [self updateScore];
            }

          _Fireball.center = CGPointMake(_Fireball.center.x, _Fireball.center.y+12);    }
    else if(theScore == 8){
        _Fireball.center = CGPointMake(_Fireball.center.x, _Fireball.center.y);

        _endLabel.text = @"You Win!";
        _endLabel.hidden = false;
        _playAgainButton.hidden = false;
    }
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    _firstTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    _lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    _Dustin.center = CGPointMake(_firstTouch.x, _Dustin.center.y);
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    _firstTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    _lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    _Dustin.center = CGPointMake(_firstTouch.x, _Dustin.center.y);
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    _firstTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    _lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    _Dustin.center = CGPointMake(_firstTouch.x, _Dustin.center.y);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your touchesBegan etc.  methods are not calling super and thus all touches are being captured by your app and cannot get through to your button.

Add a call to super to each of these methods.